# Integrate $\int x^2e^{-x^2}dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I need your advice in integrating $\int x^2e^{-x^2}dx$ by parts. I went this way, $$\int x^2e^{-x^2}dx=\int x*xe^{-x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int x e^{-x^2}dx^2$$ 
I think I need to substitute $x^2=t$. Is that correct?

Comment: Perfectly correct. The last expression above isn't, though.

Comment: @Bernard what expression is not correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Substitution $t=x^2$ is correct. Now use the Definition of the [incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function):

$\gamma(s,x) = \int_0^x t^{s-1}e^{-t} dt$. Here, $s$ is an arbitrary Exponent.

Comment: Thx, I ll try it.

Answer (score 2):

Integrating by parts gives
\begin{align}
\int x^2e^{-x^2}\, dx&=-\frac12\int x \times(-2 x)\:e^{-x^2}\, dx=-\frac12 xe^{-x^2} +\frac12\int e^{-x^2}\, dx
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Alternately, you could express $I(k)=\displaystyle\int e^{-kx^2}~dx$ in terms of the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), and then differentiate both sides with regard to *k*.